# update with case sql not working

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update 2 fields from a table, FirstName and LastName, getting the data from the same table but from the Name field which contains both first and last name.

I tried:

```
UPDATE Table SET FirstName = (SELECT CASE
                WHEN name LIKE '% %' THEN LEFT(name, Charindex(' ', name) - 1) 
                ELSE name 
                END 
                    from Table), 
LastName = (select CASE
         WHEN name LIKE '% %' THEN RIGHT(name, Charindex(' ', Reverse(name)) - 1)
       END  from Table)
```

I get the following error message: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Check your subquery. The error says itself. It cant allow more than 1  value. It has to return just one value. are you using two different tables? can see Table Only as tablename.

Comment: The answer will depend on the backend, although the message does sound like SQL server

Comment: You may need to rework it so you do not have subqueries. It seems to me that you shouldn't need those subqueries. Case statements yes, subqueries no.

Comment: You're right, Jeremy Cook! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, just the logic:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET FirstName = (CASE WHEN name LIKE '% %' THEN LEFT(name, Charindex(' ', name) - 1) 
                          ELSE name 
                     END),
        LastName = (CASE WHEN name LIKE '% %' THEN RIGHT(name, Charindex(' ', Reverse(name)) - 1)
                    END
                   );
```

Or, add a `where` statement and do two updates:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET FirstName = LEFT(name, Charindex(' ', name) - 1),
        LastName = RIGHT(name, Charindex(' ', Reverse(name)) - 1)
    WHERE name LIKE '% %';

UPDATE TABLE
    SET LastName = NULL
    WHERE name not like '% %';
```

The second may not be needed if the fields are already `NULL`.